# Loading data for the grid within form onload

Tags: c#, forms, load

I have a grid on a windows form which needs to be filled when the form loads. Data comes from the DB. Currently im calling a LoadData() within form onload. So it takes considerable amount of time to load the screen as there is a DB call.

Is this a good approach ? 
Can't i use a background worker and invoke the LoadData() asynchronously so that there wont be any delay in loading the window ?

Can someone explain me what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Loading data synchronously from database on form load is not a good approach, you should load it asynchronously on separate thread.

You can use either of the following ways:

1. Thread class
2. Background Worker

Answer (score 0):

Notes :

1. Query optimization and indexing the search traget tables
2. datagrids are complex objects and get time in updating and filling its ordinary( spcially when have more column )
3. your System hardware (Ram , CPU ,VGA, ... ) that must be considered
4. i think best approach is sort your query result and paging your result by Last code accessed and use this :

   void NextPage()
    {
      Qr="select Top N from tbl  where Code>LastCode order by Code asc";
      //reading data
      FirstCode=Drr["Code"];//for first record result
      LastCode=Drr["Code"];//for last record result
    }
    void PreviousPage()
    {
      Qr="select Top N from tbl  where Code < FirstCode order by Code asc";

   //reading data

   FirstCode=Drr["Code"];//for first record result
      LastCode=Drr["Code"];//for last record result
    }

Hope this Help

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do that using Dispatcher to load data Asynchronously After form Has Rendered

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Loaded event of the Window control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new LoadDataDelegate(LoadData));
        }

        private delegate void LoadDataDelegate();

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the data.
        /// </summary>
        private void LoadData()
        {
            List<string> numberDescriptions = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
            {

                numberDescriptions.Add("Number " + i.ToString());
            }
            listBox1.ItemsSource = numberDescriptions;
        }
```